# How do I convert an unsigned char buffer to a double in C++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, double, unsigned-char

I am trying to convert an `unsigned char` buffer array into a double.
Why does this not copy the bytes into the double as they are in the array?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    unsigned char buffer[8] = {63, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    double x = *(double*)buffer;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried doing this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    unsigned char buffer[8] = {63, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    double x ;
    memcpy(&x, buffer, sizeof(double)); //NOW USING MEMCPY
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I looked at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812155/convert-from-unsigned-char-array-to-double), but it only got the same results.  The unsigned chars {63, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} is the representation of the double number `1`.

It outputs: `3.03865e-319`.

Comment: You forgot about endianness.

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that these values are, indeed, the value 1? Did you try compiling `double d=1;` with optimization turned off, and dump the contents of this variable, in hex?

Comment: I used an online double to binary converter.  I also tried the hex version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert double between host and network byte order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616883/how-to-convert-double-between-host-and-network-byte-order)

Comment: It was because I had the numbers in big-endian style, not little-endian style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your buffer round the wrong way.  It should be:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 63}
```

(on a little-endian machine using IEEE floating point).

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/049qGzf6L7sI1pkt)